# Doubts with scatterplot: how to reproduce the marker area and unit square of [0,1]x[0,1]

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I need to generate a series of 100 random points in a unit square [0,1]x[0,1] and plot them into a scatterplot so points are green if the distance from (0,0) is less then 1; they are red otherwise.

***Furthermore, the marker area of a point (x,y) should be proportional to x+y.***

I have created the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
n = 100
x = np.random.rand(n)
y = np.random.rand(n)
colors = [('r' if cond else 'g') for cond in np.logical_and(x > 0.5, y > 0.5)]
colors = np.where(np.logical_and(x < 1, y < 1) ,'g', 'r')
plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors)
plt.show()
```

but I am not sure if:

- I have reproduced the unit square of [0,1]x[0,1];
- the marker area proportional to x + y sum;

Could please give any confirmation or in case, provide some piece of advice to suit better this requirements.
Thank you so much

Comment: This looks like some kind of homework question.  For the colors you might want `x**2 + y**2 < 1`.  For the sizes, you'd need the `s=` parameter, like `plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors, s=x+y)` or maybe `plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors, s=(x+y)*10)` .  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you mind just to drop here below a small example?

Comment: A small example: `plt.scatter(x, y, c=np.where(x**2+y**2<1, 'g', 'r), s=(x+y)*10)`